# educational sources for learning biochemistry

Tags: biochemistry

I just finished high school and am going into a biology undergraduate degree, I'm getting into biochemistry too and would like to learn more about it through online platforms or even non-fiction books to use my time effectively this summer. So far I've been using online flash cards to learn more about the jargon and would like to hear some suggestions of platforms or books to read that teach concepts strongly tied to biochemistry beyond what a basic high school curriculum would teach.

Comment: It might be prudent to find out which text books are used at your university.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several reference books for biochemistry, some more readable than others. I personally recommend two of them: (1) Lehninger *et al*. Principles of Biochemistry and (2) Voet, D., Voet, J., *et al*. Fundamentals of Biochemistry: Life at the molecular level. Both books contain the most important and basic features of each subject. The chapters are generally well written. I have to say that, from my own experience, I consider that Voet's book is more enjoyable, given that some of the sections of Lehninger's can be a bit tricky. Whichever book you choose, make sure you get relatively new editions. Good luck!

As a side note, even though biochemistry is one the first proper biology classes one takes in undergrad, there are some background requirements. Taking organic and inorganic chemistry courses before is important and some understanding of thermodynamics will certainly come in handy.

Comment: How are either of these books “online” platforms? What value are personal preferences without reference to the background required, your own background, the other courses the poster may be following, any teaching experience you may have and comparison with other books available. And these are introductory text books, not reference books. It is for these reasons that I regard text recommendations off-topic on a site devoted to answering *problems* in biology.

Comment: ''books to read that teach concepts strongly tied to biochemistry beyond what a basic high school curriculum would teach.'' I assumed he was also interested in reading non-fiction books. I do agree that adding the background needed is important (as I edited the question), but I do not think the rest is needed. As a side note, what I meant by reference books is that they are very commonly used in undergraduate courses. In your view, what is a reference book then?

Comment: I'd add Stryer et al. Biochemistry as another Option. I never read Lehninger, but compared to the Voet the Stryer is a bit of an easier and more accessible introduction in my opinion. Though it's a long time that I've read those two. You can search it for free on [NCBI Bookshelf](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK21154/), though you can't browse the book freely there.